# Can I allow users on iOS and Android to see each other's markers in Google Maps?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I already know how to let users on android see each others locations, but I'm concerned about doing it on both iOS and android letting users see one another as they run different versions. Is this possible to let users see each others markers along with infowindow content?

Comment: Possible, yes. Acceptable by Apple... Maybe... But to do it, I imagine you'd need some sort of a Database or place to store all user locations.

Comment: I've been looking into Quickblox as a BaaS. Would that do any good?

Comment: Just anything that can send and receive data should be fine.